# Непонятный краш функции

Tags: c++, c, code-injection

Ситуация следующая. Инжектировал код в блокнот и вызвал ф-цию, которая в IAT ищет ф-цию по имени.

```
PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA originalFirstThunk = NULL, firstThunk = NULL;
            originalFirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + importDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk);
            firstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + importDescriptor->FirstThunk);

            while (originalFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData != NULL)
            {
                functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + originalFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData);
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "1", "Caption", MB_OK);               
                
                if (std::string(functionName->Name).compare("GetProcAddress") == 0) // <-- crash
                {
                    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Found", "Caption", MB_OK);
                }
                else MessageBoxA(NULL, "Not Found", "Caption", MB_OK);
                ++originalFirstThunk;
                ++firstThunk;
            }
```

На этапе сравнения приложение молча крашится. Т.е. MessageBox 1 вызывается, а Found или Not Found уже не показывает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Проверяли `functionName` на валидность, может быть переменная все еще NULL?

if (!functionName) std::cerr << "functionName is nullptr" << std::endl;

Comment: @AlexF, лучше в отладчике проверять - он умеет отличать мусорный указатель от нормального. А попытка вывода, скорее всего, уронит приложение так же, как оно сейчас падает.

Comment: Не знаю, какой техникой вы пользуетесь: `Инжектировал код в блокнот`. Проверьте, допускается ли использование `string` и других классов из C++ Library в инжектированном коде.

Comment: @James, нет, не null, проверял.

Comment: @j0hn, ты там что-то добавляешь - естественно, он не null, но вот мусором оказаться может. Хотя идея про string мне больше нравится.

Comment: @Alex F Спасибо